# Сделать ссылку на телеграм

Tags: html, css, telegram

Вот как сейчас

```
<a href="tg://resolve?domain=+79146873100" target="_blank"></a>
```

Так не работает. Как правильно сделать?
Нужно для этого сайта https://gotendergo.ru/

Comment: Пробовали вместо телефона писать username?

Comment: Спасибо! Сработало!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По номеру телефона сделать ссылку на телегу нельзя - используйте username:

```
<a href="tg://resolve?domain=username">Написать автору</a>
```